# Experimental question regarding uncertainties

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-technique

I am not sure exactly how to deal with my uncertainties from an experiment I recently did.

While taking measurements, I estimated an uncertainty in each result based on my ability to accurately read off of the vernier scale. So, say 1 minute of arc. 
I also took multiple readings of the same angle resulting in a good set of data, allowing me to calculate a mean value and a standard error of the mean. I'm confused about which uncertainties I use for plotting my data and continuing with my analysis. On the one hand, I have an estimated uncertainty for each measurement of a set amount but on the other, I have an average and an uncertainty on the average.

Do I just use the average uncertainty since it gives a better representation of the error based on the spread of the results? But then it seems like it was pointless having an estimated unc'ty since that would only be useful without repeated measurements.

Comment: In that situation you would usually report the standard deviation of your measurement.

Comment: @lemon Ok great. That's what I was leaning towards but I don't understand why we were told to make an estimate on our uncertainties if it's just going to be overridden by standard error anyway.

Comment: If you have estimated your uncertainties correctly then the standard deviation (of the population, not of the mean) you compute will be of similar size to you individual uncertainty estimates, so this is a check on your uncertainty estimating skill. Moreover, a more sophisticated means of computing your mean and standard deviation would use the individual uncertainty estimates to weight the value of each observation in computing the mean in the first place.